# Is it possible to conditionally format the color of a line without skipping points in between the "positive" values in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sorry for the awkward title, but this is a weird little issue and I'm not sure how to better describe it.

Basically, I want to **conditionally color** a line in a time plot so that it's red when a condition is met and gray when it's not.

However, sometimes there are *condition == FALSE* values in between the *condition == TRUE* points, which causes the red line to jump over the *condition == FALSE* values (example below).

Note in the example that the red line at *time == 6* jumps to *time == 16*, bypassing the three intermittent points.

I have tried setting the *NA* values to 0, but that doesn't seem to help.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
df_plot <- tibble(
  id = rep(1, times = 10),
  time = seq(from = 0, to = 25, length.out = 10), 
  y_val = c(seq(from = 50, to = 25, length.out = 5),
            seq(from = 25, to = 50, length.out = 5)),
  con_val = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 2))
  
ggplot(data = df_plot, aes(x = time, y = y_val, color = con_val > 0)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = setNames(c('red','gray'), c(T, F)))
```

[image: An example of what I do not want.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a a single group, because without one `ggplot2` uses `color` as a group by default

```
ggplot(data = df_plot, aes(x = time, y = y_val, color = con_val > 0, group = 1)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = setNames(c('red','gray'), c(T, F)))
```

[image]