# Using ggplot in R to display dataframe with two different colours depending on value of data. Issue with Data jumping

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, graph

I am using the below code to plot a data frame on the same plot:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_line(aes(x = date, y = values, colour = X > 5))
```

The plot is working and looks great all except for the fact that when the values are bigger than 5, because I am using geom_line, it then starts connecting points that are above the threshold. like below. I do not want the lines connecting the blue data.

How do I stop this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to conditionally format the color of a line without skipping points in between the "positive" values in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185490/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-format-the-color-of-a-line-without-skipping-poin)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the `economics` dataset included in `ggplot2`.  You see the same thing if we highlight the line based on values above 8000:

```
ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=unemploy > 8000))
```

[image]

When a mapping is defined in your dataset, by default `ggplot2` also groups your data based on this.  This makes total sense if you're trying to plot a line where you have data in long form and want to draw separate lines for each different value in a column.  In cases like this, you want `ggplot2` to change the color of the line based on the data, but you want to tell `ggplot2` *not to group* based on color.  This is why you will need to override the `group=` aesthetic.

To override the `group=` aesthetic change that happens when you map your line geom, you can just say `group=1` or really `group=` any constant value.  This effectively sets every observation mapped to the same group, and the line will connect all your points, but be colored differently:

```
ggplot(economics, aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=unemploy > 8000, group=1))
```

[image]